# Dynamically add items to a collection in MVC2 using EditorFor()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to do this: [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

In the post he mentions that it could be done with less code using Html.EditorFor(), but that it would be more difficult because of the indexes. Well, that's exactly what I want to do, and I don't know where to begin.

I'm an ASP.NET novice who just completed the Nerd Dinner tutorial before jumping into a project at work, so any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1:** Instead of generating a GUID for each item in the collection, I'd like to generate incremental indexes starting with 0. Right now the field names look like "gifts[GUID].value"; I would like them to be "gifts[0].value","gifts[1](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).value" etc. but I don't understand how the collection keeps track and generates these indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you begin by defining an editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Gift.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.Gift>" %>
<div class="editorRow">
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts")) { %>
        Item: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %> 
        Value: $<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { size = 4 }) %> 
    <% } %>
</div>
```

And then replace the `RenderPartial` call with `EditorForModel`:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <div id="editorRows">
        <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Finished" />
<% } %>
```

Once you've tried this you may come back and ask if you have any problems by explaining the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the summary with details about where I am now.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your update about generating indexes instead of GUIDs, the original linked article had a few comments from others that tried to solve the same issue but none of them worked for me.  What I found was the collection with index was referenced in the following location:

```
html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

So I wrote a helper function to parse out the index (and if there is a problem then the GUID would be generated)

```
public static string GetCollectionItemIndex(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
     {
     int idx;
     string sIdx;

     if (Int32.TryParse(Regex.Match(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, @"\d+").Value, out idx))
        {
        sIdx = idx.ToString();
        }
     else
        {
        sIdx = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

     return sIdx;
     }
```

I edited the BeginCollectionItem(..) function to call this helper function when setting the item index:

```
     string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : GetCollectionItemIndex(html, collectionName);
```

Hope this helps someone else!